# Conserved charge from conserved current associated with translational invariance

Tags: special-relativity, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem, classical-field-theory

(c.f Di Francesco, 'Conformal Field Theory' P.45)
Di Francesco calls the conserved charge arising from the conserved current associated with a translation invariant theory the 'four momentum'.  While I see why such a result makes sense, what was the motivation for calling it so?

Also, why is it called the four momentum? Di Francesco's treatment seems to be valid in not only four space time dimensions but in a space time with $d$ space time dimensions.  This is evident in his portrayal of the conserved charge $P^{\nu}$ defined like $$P^{\nu} = \int \text{d}^{d-1} x T^{0 \nu},$$ where $T^{\mu \nu}$ is the stress energy tensor.  So should the conserved charge not be called something like a $d$ momentum so that we define $P^{\nu}$ analogously to the familiar 4D Minkowksi setting of special relativity with $P^{\nu} = (E, \mathbf{P})$, where $\mathbf{P}$ is the $d-1$ momenta in the same vein that in SR, we refer to the $3$ momenta?

Comment: As indicated in the book, the conserved current associated to the translation invariance is the energy-momentum tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$, whose components are the density and flux of momenta and energy. $T_{0\nu}$ is the momentum/energy density, so integrated, it gives the momentum/energy as conserved quantity.

The "four-momentum" word before formula $(2.166)$, is an imprecision (or a typo, if you prefer)

Comment: Thanks very much. So essentially if $d=4$ then the four momentum term would make sense? If so, do you agree that we could say $P^{\nu}$ is like a $d$ momentum with $\mathbf{P}$ a $d-1$ momenta in the general case?

Comment: The total "$d$-momentum", (used in special relativity, for instance) , $P^\nu = (P^0,\mathbf{P})$ is made of the energy ($P_0$), its time component, and the spatial momentum ($\mathbf{P}$), its spatial components.

Comment: A quick somewhat unrelated question: why do we regard energy as a time like component?

Comment: Special relativity unifies space and time into a single pattern : space-time. This is described by a quadrivector $x^\mu$ whose first component is time ($x^0$), and other components are space coordinates. A change of reference frame may transform space coordinate into time coordinate, and vice-versa. There is also a unification of momentum and energy in the momentum/energy quadrivector $p^\mu$.

Comment: When we say $T^{\mu \nu}$ has momentum/energy densities as its components, what is this referring to? Does it describe these parameters for some physical system?

Comment: Finally, if $T^{\mu \nu}$ has components as the momentum/energy densities, why is it that the components $T^{0 \nu}$ give rise to the energy and momentum present in the $d$ momentum? What I mean to say is, if $T^{o\nu}$ gives the energy/momentum density then what does $T^{1\nu}$ give for example?

Comment: $T^{i\mu}, i=1,2,3$ gives the flux of energy/momentum, and $T^{0\mu}$ gives the density of energy/momentum. From each system described by some field, one is able to obtain the stress-energy tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$ from the Lagrangian describing the system.